# Why in superconducting cylindrical thin tube of radius $R$ the magentic field lines would be exactly parallel to the axis of cylinder?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

Consider a superconducting cylindrical coil of length $L$ radius $R$ and having a current I around its mantle, **(Assume that current causes magentic field which passes through the superconductor area at T>Tc(critical temperature for superconductor) after that its switches to T<Tc so that field lines still are there inside**) Now my question:  **why its true that the field lines inside the cylinder would always be parallel to the axis and if its true why it will be uniform also just in case it also happens**? What can we say regarding outside field? If its zero outside why is it so? And whats the difference in this and a solenoid of same length L and radius R in terms of magnetic fields at various locations? **Is there no approximation being made in case of the former one while calculating any field as such** (i.e there is no edge effects at all in former etc.)? Setup consists of just a superconducting cylinder and somehow the current is flowing outside of cylinder in helical pattern around thee cylindrical surface, if length ,radius are comparable , even then we observe that field value is is always uniform inside why ? (**This "current passing  setup" was done so as to calculate the self inductance of the superconducting cylinder**)

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the geometry of the system. Are you considering a full cylinder of superconducting material, a superconducting cylindrical shell or a solenoid made with a coil of superconducting material? What is the "mantle"?

Comment: Mantle means the curved surface of cylinder where current is moving around in helical but nearly many circlular loops and yes i am considering a full cylinder of superconducting material . Lastly i was referring to difference between this and normal solenoid . In terms of magnetic field lines and other stuffs

Comment: if your superconducting material is type 1 then you can do the "field cooling". You impose a certain uniform B outside the sample in its normal state, along the axis of rhe cylinder. You cool down rhe sample, at B constant. Then you go below the transition temperature the same becomes superconducting: persistent surface currents will develop on the cylindrical surface (circulating around the axis of the cylinder) that shield the B from the interior (Meissner effect).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695558/226902

Comment: Its a bit different @Quillo , i am asking for a cylinder (superconducting ) in which a current is flowing in a helical patttern on the curve surface , my question was inside field value will be uniform , why that is what i am asking . (Nothing more is present there )

Comment: The field inside is uniform and zero, because of Meissener effect. The presence of the surface current is exactly what shields the interior from the external field that must be used to create the surface supercurrent.

Comment: Quillo i am telling it already having field inside it due to current flowing around it (you can say that intially it was not at T>Tc and later its goes to T<Tc ) now describe the field lines @Quillo

Comment: There is no external field here given also @Quillo

Comment: So,  how do you create the supercurrent?

Comment: You have to explain the full experimental procedure in detail. For example..  Is the sample zero field cooled or field cooled? Is it type 1 or type 2?

Comment: Also: modify the question to add details and make it clear. This will increase the visibility of you question and  you will have a chance to get an answer before the bounty expires.

Comment: Oh i see sure @Quillo adding more details

Comment: Added very more details and why it was wanted @Quillo